# Table 3 foreign key, either has a value and a null

Tags: mysql

So i have a users table. user can be author or a normal user. There's no defining column that says a user is an author, only in the story table where there's a foreign key(author_id = user.user_id).

Now i want to add a review function. User can review either a story and an author and can also rate a chapter.

So my table looks like this:

```
**review**
review_id(PK AI)
user_id(FK - user.user_id)//reviewer NOT NULL
author_id(FK - user.user_id)//reviewee NULL
story_id(FK - story.story_id)//reviewee NULL
chapter_id(FK - chapter.chapter_id)//reviewee NULL

**review_content**
review_content_id(PK AI)
review_id(FK)
rating decimal
content text
date_added datetime
```

Since user_id in the user_table, story_id in the story table and chapter_id in the chapter table are all PK AI. There is a 100% chance of duplicate/same values.

For example: user_id(5) reviewed author(10). user_id(5) also reviewed story_id(10), or user_id(5) rated chapter_id(10).

So to identify if a review is for a story/author/chapter. I plan to just null other FK and insert a value to the relevant FK.

If a review is for a story, then story_id(FK) will have a value meanwhile author_id and chapter_id will be null.

so in my query it will be:

```
//fetch review for story
$this->db->from('review');
$this->db->where('author_id', NULL);
$this->db->where('story_id', $story_id);
$this->db->where('chapter_id', NULL);
$this->db->get()->result();
```

I want to know if my table design is correct. Or should i stick to making different review tables(author,story,chapter).

I really wanted to write reusable methods for the 3 instead of making 3 for each types.

For example: checking whether review exists. Inserting reviews. fetching. etc. If i were to make 3 different tables then i would have to make 3 different methods for each functions.

Comment: Cool story bro. Was there a *question*?

Comment: Is my table design for review correct?

Comment: This site is for problems if you have any. There are other sites that will help you with reviewing your design or code. Try codereview.stackexchange.com or dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This would be off-topic on Code Review as it is. If you include the complete data definition language query that creates the schema/tables/functions, then it should be fine. I don't think DBA would do a schema review either, they're more about database administration related problems.

Comment: I just want to know if there are problems with my current table. 

Where do i go to ask for database design problems? Other problems are solvable with a little bit of searching but designs are a bit harder to search as they differ from person to person. so i can't find any question thats atleast 80% identical to mine.